# how to solve the problem when the data from localStorage has been deleted when leaving crome there is only 1 data left

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When I have deleted the bookmark data from localStorage and closed my website tab or closed Chrome when I visited my website again why is there still one data left which is the data I deleted most recently.

my code is like this

```
  const [bookmark, setBookmark] = useState([]);

  const addToBookmark = (ayatLs) => {
    setBookmark([...bookmark, ayatLs]);
  };

  const removeBookmark = (bookmarkToRemove) => {
    setBookmark(bookmark.filter((x) => x !== bookmarkToRemove));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (bookmark.length === 0) return;
    localStorage.setItem('bookmark', JSON.stringify(bookmark));
  }, [bookmark]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const bookmarkFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('bookmark');

    const parsedBookmark =
      bookmarkFromLocalStorage !== null
        ? JSON.parse(bookmarkFromLocalStorage)
        : [];

    setBookmark(parsedBookmark);
  }, []);
```

Comment: _"When I have deleted the bookmark data from localStorage"_ where is this in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your "update" `useEffect`.

If you remove an Item from you `bookmark` array, your code does the following:

Let's say you start off with two elements in your `bookmark` array, so:

---

`bookmark.length === 2` localStorage has two items in it,

then you run `removeBookmark`, the array get's copied with just one element,

the first useEffect gets triggered by the updated `bookmark` variable, and the new array (with length 1, right) gets written to localStorage.

---

Now `bookmark.length === 1`, and you run `removeBookmark` again.

The `bookmark` array is now empty, so `bookmark.length === 0`, so the if-statement `if (bookmark.length === 0) return;` makes it so there are no more changes to your localStorage, thus the last item is never removed, and there is still one item in your localStorage array.

---

If you change the useEffect to just this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('bookmark', JSON.stringify(bookmark));
}, [bookmark]);
```

There should just be an empty array in your localStorage when you remove the last item.

Comment: it worked but why when i refresh the page the data in localStorage goes blank

Comment: Just a guess... Try putting the bookmark useEffect after the one that reads from localstorage, if they are callled in the order that they are in the code, the problem should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Here you are setting the data in **localstorage** using the **useEffect**. Once the value is set in **localstorage**, it stays there till it's not deleted manually using **localStorage.removeItem("key");**. Here removing the value from **bookmark** won't work.

You need to use **.removeItem('key')** to do so.
Doing this will remove the whole value from **localstorage**. So you have to re-store the values in **localstorage**.